# How to use Findstr to extract multiple line text from one file and output into another

Tags: batch-file

I have a piece of software that is outputting log files and I'm trying to write a batch file that will extract the lines with error's and dump them into a separate text file. So far I have a batch file that will copy the first line but that doesn't work as some errors can span across multiple lines.

The example log file I have is Test.txt:

```
2017-05-18 |Status| <<Everything is working great>>
2017-5-18 |Error| <<Error message here and continues on, sometimes for multiple lines>>
2017-5-18 |Status| <<Things are great again>>
```

The batch file I wrote to extract the error is:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N /C:"|Error|" Test.txt') do echo %%b) > output.txt
```

This somewhat works because it'll extract the lines that contain |Error| however error messages that are longer it cuts off after the first line. I want to have it copy the enter block that says |Error| all the way to the ">>"

Comment: You might be better off working with real regular expressions in PowerShell or j-/vbscript.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q44057323.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"

SET "output="
(
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 SET "errorline="
 SET "chevrons="
 ECHO "%%a"|FIND /i "|error|">NUL
 IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 SET "errorline=Y"
 ECHO "%%a"|FIND /i ">>">NUL
 IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 SET "chevrons=Y"
 IF DEFINED errorline SET  "output=Y"
 IF DEFINED output ECHO %%a
 IF DEFINED chevrons SET "output="
)
)>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q44057323.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Produces the file defined as %outfile%

It would have been better if you'd included an example of a multi-line error. As it is, we're forced to conclude that `>>` marks the end of the message and that this only appears at the end of the message.

Read each line, detect the presence of the target strings and set the switches as appropriate. Turn **ON** outputting if the first string is detected, turn **OFF** outputting if the second is found.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you. I'm still new to batch file scripting and this is a big help

Answer (score 0):

The following code accomplishes the task you want:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_FILE=.\Test.txt"
set "_RETURN=.\output.txt" & if not defined _RETURN set "_RETURN=con"
set "_BEGIN=|Error| <<" & rem // (case-insensitive search string)
set "_END=>>"           & rem // (case-insensitive search string)

rem // Count number of lines:
for /F %%C in ('^< "!_FILE!" find /C /V ""') do (
    rem // Reset flag:
    set "FLAG="
    rem // Read and write files by redirection:
    < "!_FILE!" > "!_RETURN!" (
        rem // Loop through all lines:
        for /L %%I in (1,1,%%C) do (
            rem // Read a single line:
            set "LINE=" & set /P LINE=""
            rem // Set flag if line contains search string a block begins with:
            if not "!LINE!"=="!LINE:%_BEGIN%=!" set "FLAG=#"
            rem // Return current line only in case flag is set:
            if defined FLAG echo(!LINE!
            rem // Reset flag if line contains search string a block ends with:
            if not "!LINE!"=="!LINE:%_END%=!" set "FLAG="
        )
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

Note that this fails in case the file contains more than 2147483647 lines and/or if any line contains more than 1023 characters/bytes.